# can somebody help me to correct my following code at the styling point in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, styles, python-3.6

```
for idx,ids in enumerate(uniq):
    SV = df_CenteredWin[df_CenteredWin['subVoyageIDs'] == ids]

    SV['minGroup']= np.isnan(SV.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('30T')).DateTime.diff().dt.seconds)
    SV['groups'] = (SV['minGroup'].shift(1) != SV['minGroup']).astype(int).cumsum()
    SV_Noise = SV[SV['zScore_Noise'] == 'noise']
    uniqueID= SV_Noise.groups.unique()

    print(uniqueID, SV_Noise.subVoyageIDs.unique())

    for idx, groupid in enumerate(uniqueID):
        groups = SV[SV['groups'] == groupid]
        groups_nosie = groups[groups['zScore_Noise'] == 'noise']
        data = pd.DataFrame(data = { 'distance' : groups.Distance,
                       'Speed' : groups.Speed,
                        'Z-Score' :  groups.centeredZScore,
                         'flagged' :  groups.zScore_Noise.values})
        display(data.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: Yellow' if x.name == 'noise' else data for i in x]))
```

can anyone explain me what is wrong in this line, and how can I correct it

```
display(data.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: Yellow' if x.name == 'noise' else data for i in x]))
```

I have this following data where i am trying to highlight the row where the flagged column is equal to 'noise'

```
 DateTime            Speed      Score        Distance   flagged
2011-01-09 12:21:59 1.840407   -0.845713    0.030673    noisefree
2011-01-09 12:23:00 4.883493    2.307917    0.082748    noisefree
2011-01-09 12:24:00 4.413968    1.752545    0.073566    noisefree
2011-01-09 12:24:59 4.950600    2.178342    0.081135    noisefree
2011-01-09 12:26:00 10.014879   4.355568    0.169697    noise
2011-01-09 12:27:00 7.534325    2.535460    0.125572    noisefree
2011-01-09 12:27:59 6.965328    2.122056    0.114154    noisefree
2011-01-09 12:29:00 6.993480    1.963185    0.118501    noisefree
```

and the error is:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Comment: well I will say thar's kinda duplicate, but I posted because I tried that code and got some error, and I tried hard to find mistake which I did not find it, thanks for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. I'm not exactly sure why you got THAT error, but one issue was that you were returning your initial dataframe within the `else` block of your list comprehension.

If you replace that line with this, you may have better luck.

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: yellow" if v == "noise" else "" for v in x], axis = 1)
```

In this case, you are iterating over each row in your `df`, highlighting cells that equal `noise`.

Help from / possible duplicate of [Conditionally format Python pandas cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell)

Edit:
Ripping off @scott-boston and [How to use Python Pandas Stylers for coloring an entire row based on a given column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596579/how-to-use-python-pandas-stylers-for-coloring-an-entire-row-based-on-a-given-col),

```
def highlight_row(s,keyword,column):
    is_keyword = pd.Series(data=False, index=s.index)
    is_keyword[column] = s.loc[column] == keyword
    return ['background-color: yellow' if is_keyword.any() else '' for v in is_keyword]

df.style.apply(highlight_row, keyword="noise", column=["flagged"], axis=1)
```

Comment: well I guess that was the mistake which was generating this error, in the else i was returning my initial DataFrame, which was wrong in this case, well thank you so much for correcting me, I have one more question, this is just highlighting one word, how can I highlight the full row?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596579/how-to-use-python-pandas-stylers-for-coloring-an-entire-row-based-on-a-given-col

Comment: well thanks but, I already did it, thank you so much for your kind help

Comment: that was really helpful since, you corrected my first mistake, thanks a lot