# How can I color the empty rows in and export to an excel file with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I am trying to automate a few tasks on excel, some include setting the cells without any values in red color (empty cells in my DataFrame dimensions and not outside it), I tried the following after checking previous similar answers:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(r'input.xls', sheet_name='sheet1')
print(df)

df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : yellow' if x>1 else '')


# create excel writer object
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'Output.xls')

# write dataframe to excel
df.to_excel(writer)
# save the excel
writer.save()
print('DataFrame is written successfully to Excel File.')
```

I've also tried other ways like

```
def color(row):
    if row.isnull().values.any() == True:
        return ['background-color: red'] * len(row)
    return [''] * len(row)

# Apply the function
df.style.apply(color, axis=1)
```

None of which seem to work, in the console I am getting the proper values printed and I am getting an output file with the additional row enumeration from 0, but nothing is getting colored in the output excel file

My dataset in excel has x by y dimensions and each cell can contain numbers(decimal) or text depending on the column name

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596579/how-to-use-pandas-stylers-for-coloring-an-entire-row-based-on-a-given-column/43601040?noredirect=1#comment133163644_43601040) Q/A is related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pandas [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) object is a separate object from the `df` which creates it. To write out a styled DataFrame to excel we need to use the actual Styler object not `df`. The easiest way to do this is to use [Styler.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html):

```
# Save Styler Object for Later
styler = df.style
# Apply Styles (This can be chained or on separate lines)
styler.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : yellow' if x > 1 else '')
styler.apply(color, axis=1)
# Export the styler to excel
styler.to_excel('Output.xls', index=False)
```

Method chaining also works:

```
df.style \
    .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : yellow' if x > 1 else '') \
    .apply(color, axis=1) \
    .to_excel('Output.xls', index=False)
```

*Note: `index=False` ensures that the DataFrame index is not included in the output. (the "additional row enumeration from 0")

---

We can also use [pd.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with the [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) in a similar way:

```
# Save Styler Object for Later
styler = df.style
# Apply Styles (This can be chained or on separate lines)
styler.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : yellow' if x > 1 else '')
styler.apply(color, axis=1)

with pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xls') as writer:
    styler.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

---

As a general improvement, we can set Styles at the DataFrame level by passing `axis=None` to [Styler.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) and performing all modifications in one function:

```
def color(df_):
    styles_df = pd.DataFrame('', index=df_.index, columns=df_.columns)
    # Color cells yellow where they are greater than 1
    styles_df[df_ > 1] = 'background-color: yellow'
    # Color rows red where there are any null values across rows
    styles_df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), :] = 'background-color: red'
    return styles_df


with pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xls') as writer:
    df.style.apply(color, axis=None).to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks now they're getting colored but facing a weird issue when i put the condition as styler.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : yellow' if x ==None else '') it didn't color anything and when i put it as x==0 it colored even the text False but didn't color any empty cells

Comment: So that's more of a general python logic issue unrelated to the actual pandas styling. `== None` is unlikely to give the expected results especially in pandas with the various different ways None-like data can be stored. Additionally it sounds like you have a boolean column. In python `False == 0` evaluates to `True` which is why it's being coloured.

Comment: If you need help with specific styles based on specific styling rules you could put together a new question with a sample DataFrame `df = pd.DataFrame({... sample data ...})` then explain how it should be styled. Someone may be able to help you define your styling rules appropriately.