# Color a Pandas DataFrame column based on distinct values

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks something like this

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({"Country":['xx','xx','xy','xz','xz'],
               "year":['y1','y2','y1','y1','y2'],
               "population":[100,200,120,140,190]})
```

What would be the best way to highlight all the distinct countries in a particular column in different colors?
That would mean, the three distinct countries in the "country" column ("xx","xy","xz") needs to be highlighted in different colors each.

***EDIT*** : These values are generated dynamically and can be different each time. So I am guessing hard coding the colors based on the values is not an option

Comment: this has already been answered in SO. Check this out,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596579/how-to-use-pandas-stylers-for-coloring-an-entire-row-based-on-a-given-column

Comment: @AlexRajanSamuel I think the question seems to talk about how to highlight a row if the values exceed a certain threshold. I don't understand how its related to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list of colors and make a mapping dictionary from the list of countries, then use `style.applymap`:

```
import matplotlib

colors = dict(zip(d1['Country'].unique(),
                  (f'background-color: {c}' for c in matplotlib.colors.cnames.values())))

d1.style.applymap(colors.get, subset=['Country'])
```

output:

[image]

Comment: And if i want to apply the coloring to the entire dataFrame..... is there a way to achieve that?