# PandasTable: Highlight greatest value per group

Tags: python, pandas, greatest-n-per-group, pandastable

I'm new to Python.
I have a dataframe and a datatable to show it in a GUI.
[image]

**Step 1:**
For every couple of unique values in column A and B, I need to search for the maximum value in column 'C'
I managed to do it with groupby (see code)
In this picture, you can see the result of Groupby, with the max values in column C.

[image]

**Step2**
For every couple of unique values in column A and B, I need to highlight the corresponding max value in column C.
The result should be like this:
[image]

Can somebody help me, please?

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['alfa','beta','alfa','alfa','beta','beta'],
    'B': ['a','a','a','b','a','a'],
    'C': [1,2,3,4,7,6],
})

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

pt = Table(frame1, dataframe=df) 
pt.show()

print(df.loc[df.groupby(["A", "B"])["C"].idxmax()] )

pt.setColorByMask( 'C', pt.model.df.iloc[:, 2] == pt.model.df.iloc[:, 2].max(),  'lightgreen'  )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: for step 2: do  you mean you want to highlight the entire row that max value appears? if so, you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596579/how-to-use-pandas-stylers-for-coloring-an-entire-row-based-on-a-given-column

Comment: For step 2, I want to highlight, for every couple of unique values in column A and B, the corresponding max value in column C. I'll edit my question because maybe is not clear. Thank you Paul

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column in `df`, indicating if it contains the max value. This column can then be used as a color mask in `setColorByMask`
For example like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['alfa','beta','alfa','gamma','beta','delta'],
    'B': ['a','b','a','b','a','b'],
    'C': [1,2,3,4,7,6],
})

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

pt = Table(frame1, dataframe=df)
pt.show()

max_value_rows = df.loc[df.groupby(["A", "B"])["C"].idxmax()]

print(max_value_rows)

df['color_mask'] = False
df['color_mask'][max_value_rows.index] = True
color_mask = df['color_mask']

pt.setColorByMask( 'C', color_mask,  'lightgreen'  )

root.mainloop()
```

Edit:
You can also create the color mask like this:

```
max_value_rows = df.loc[df.groupby(["A", "B"])["C"].idxmax()]

color_mask = pd.Series(len(df) * [False])
color_mask[max_value_rows.index] = True

pt.setColorByMask( 'C', color_mask,  'lightgreen'  )
```

Comment: Andrzej, thank you for your answer: this is a first working solution.
In the reality my dataframe will contain 18 columns to check and more than 20000 rows.
So I would prefer to avoid to add 18 new columns.

Comment: @Chakot I have updated my answer, you can create the color mask without changing the dataframe