# How to highlight specific rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, highlight

For example I want to be able to highlight the first 17 rows in green in a dataframe. I've seen answers on how to highlight rows based on column value but nothing as simple as rows regardless of the value in a column. I don't care about the value in the rows.

TLDR: I just simply want to be able to color the first 17 rows green in a dataframe.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `DataFrame` does not have notion of color for rows. Depending on where the output is (unclear at the moment), it may be possible to achieve such representation. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43596579/4046632

Comment: (the previously associated duplicate Q&A is, as its title suggests, achieves conditional styling over values in cells; this question asks for value-independent styling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.style.applymap(lambda _: "background-color: green", subset=(df.index[:17],))
```

where we subset the styling area with a tuple to say we select rows (if tuple is stripped off, it interprets them as column names). Noting that we cannot directly write `range(17)` there as not all dataframes have the default RangeIndex (0, 1 ...). Since we don't really care about the value residing in cells but the row index itself, `_` is used in the coloring function to convey ignoring that.

Generalization for the first N rows:

```py
# Color first N rows
N, color = 17, "lightgray"
df.style.applymap(lambda _: f"background-color: {color}", subset=(df.index[:N],))
```

Generalization for specific rows:

```py
# Color specific rows
rows_to_color = [0, 4, 5, 12]
color = "lightgray"
df.style.applymap(lambda _: f"background-color: {color}",
                  subset=(df.index[rows_to_color],))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going beyond and also giving me how to do specific rows not just the first couple or last couple. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

One option would to be [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) a [*background-color*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) on a `subset` of rows :

```
color = "lime"
N = 7 # adjust here

(
    df.style.apply(
        lambda _: [f"background-color: {color}"]*N,
        subset=pd.IndexSlice[:N])
)
```

Output :

[image]

Used input :

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col1": np.random.randn(10),
     "col2": np.random.randn(10),
     "col3": np.random.randn(10)
    }
)
```